# List of airlines and aircraft types at Copenhagen Airport (CPH)

Tags: airline-operations

Is there a website with a list of all the airlines that fly to Copenhagen Airport (CPH), and with what aircraft types they fly to Copenhagen?

I have found a list of airlines at the website from Copenhagen Airport, but no cargo airlines are mentioned there, and also no aircraft types. I have started with that list and typing over the aircraft types from the complete fleet from Wikipedia or the website of the airline itself, and then looking at Flightradar 24 which aircraft of the fleet is actually used to fly to and from CPH, but it takes a really long time and due to summer/winter schedules I will probably miss out on some.

Or if anyone has tips for a faster (and more accurate) solution if such a list does not exist...

Answer (score 1):

This can be obtained from the Eurocontrol Data, if you are a student they might allow you to acces the data:
https://ext.eurocontrol.int/

You have to request for an account there.